# Newbie trying to sideload on Glass XE22 - getting "offline" in adb

Tags: adb, google-glass, sideloading

I am trying to figure out how to side load an app to my Google Glass.  It is on XE22.

I did all of the simple things like adding adb and updating the .inf file.  but when I do ADB DEVICE it says my serial number and then "offline".   I tried multiple factory resets, and then got it to say "unauthorized."  I did a few more things (i.e. turing off debug, unpluging, killing server, starting server, pluging back in...) and I got the prompt to "allow / trust computer."  Once I did that it looked good and said my serial number and "device."  I then tried to load Launchy.apk and it said "adb server is out of date. killing... *daemon started successfully*" and then it said "error: Device Offline" and now it shows off-line again.

How can I sideload to Google Glass?